# How to make the length of the <hr> tag the same size as the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to create a line across my page, just under the Breaking News title but it should have the same length as the contents of my Flexbox under it.

What I would like to achieve:

[image: sample]

The Breaking News text should also be aligned with my flexbox. Ergo I placed both of them inside the Flexbox. The problem now is that:

1. for me to get my desired outcome I need to set a fixed width, but this will affect the responsiveness of my side, some content stays hidden when you drag and minimize the browser
2. if I don't set fixed width, the line takes all the space in my flexbox.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
}

.main-header {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20;
}

.secondary-header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.breaking-news-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 25px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.breaking-news-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px black;
  border-style: dotted;
}

.breaking-news-images {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: top;
}

.breaking-news-titles {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.breaking-news-paragraph {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.first-line {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="breaking-news-title"> Breaking news </div>
<hr class="first-line" />
<div class="breaking-news-container">
  <div class="breaking-news-box">
    <img class="breaking-news-images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/320/200">
    <h3 class="breaking-news-titles">Missing dog found alive after 6 days</h3>
    <p class="breaking-news-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum odit cum. Provodient sin autem se olum ad enim sunt totam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="breaking-news-box">
    <img class="breaking-news-images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1048/320/200">
    <h3 class="breaking-news-titles">Elon Musk investigated over Twitter deal</h3>
    <p class="breaking-news-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum odit cum. Provodient sin autem se olum ad enim sunt totam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="breaking-news-box">
    <img class="breaking-news-images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/117/320/200">
    <h3 class="breaking-news-titles">Billie Eilish announces Happier That Ever world tour</h3>
    <p class="breaking-news-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum odit cum. Provodient sin autem se olum ad enim sunt totam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="breaking-news-box">
    <img class="breaking-news-images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/160/320/200">
    <h3 class="breaking-news-titles">EU approves common charging cable from 2024</h3>
    <p class="breaking-news-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum odit cum. Provodient sin autem se olum ad enim sunt totam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found something about making the hr a pseudo element but it doesn't work.
Any thoughts?

Comment: You have the flex items set to `justify-content: center`. Hence, they will be bunched together in the center of the row, leaving space on the sides. If you want the items always aligned with the headline and the `hr`, and don't want to use a fixed width, try `justify-content: space-between` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/6oftc3he/

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `hr`? If you'r only using it as a visual divider, you could simply add `border-bottom` to the `div.breaking-news-title` above or `border-top` to the `div.breaking-new-container` below.